# Add new label to Docker image with Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-image

I have the following Ansible role:

```
- name: pull image
  docker_image:
    name: "mpioperator/tensorflow-benchmarks"
```

I would like to know how can I add a custom label to it.

I need a custom label because I would like to use `docker image prune` later on and I want a `do_not_delete` kind of label to filter out the images I want to keep.

Update:

As @dschuldt has mentioned there's no way to add additional labels to an already existing image because that would result in an entirely new image. I would be perfectly fine with a solution like this, however as I see in the [documentation of the docker_image module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html) there's no way to add more labels to an image. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. Labels are set during build time. Adding a label would modify the Image layer checksums. You need to rebuild the Image (what you can sure do with Ansible).

Comment: I'm rather new to Docker, so allow me to ask: could you give me an example docker cli command to rebuild an image from a repository? If all else fails I could just use the `shell` module in Ansible. I've also updated my question.

Comment: Write a simple Dockerfile with FROM <Imagename> and LABEL do_not_delete=true. Then build the Image with either Ansible Shell Module (docker build -t ....) or with Ansible docker Image Module.